# python check if bit in sequence is true or false

Tags: python, bit

I want to find if a bit in a sequense is 1 or 0 (true or false)
if i have some bitsequense of 11010011, how can i check if the 4th position is True or False?

example:

```
10010101 (4th bit) -> False
10010101 (3rd bit) -> True
```

Comment: Are you counting from left or right?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Without the bit shifting:

```
if bits & 0b1000:
    ...
```

**EDIT:** Actually, `(1 << 3)` is optimized out by the compiler.

```
>>> dis.dis(lambda x: x & (1 << 3))
  1           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
              3 LOAD_CONST               3 (8)
              6 BINARY_AND          
              7 RETURN_VALUE        
>>> dis.dis(lambda x: x & 0b1000)
  1           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
              3 LOAD_CONST               1 (8)
              6 BINARY_AND          
              7 RETURN_VALUE
```

The two solutions are equivalent, choose the one that looks more readable in your context.

Comment: It would be more appropriate to show timeit results of both ... disassembly can be misleading sometimes

Comment: @JoranBeasley: not in this case. Except for `co_consts`, the bytecode is the same. Also, timeit is not ideal for such fast one-liners and should be used with extreme care (you risk measuring the overhead of the `for` loop used by timeit).

Comment: `x&(1<<3)` is marginally faster in every test ive ran (which is actually somewhat suprising)

Comment: @JoranBeasley: my tests do not agree. BTW, this is the code you should run: `timeit('x & 0b1000\n' * 1000, 'x = 5')`. (Note the `* 1000` -- if you didn't do that, then you've measured the speed of `itertools.repeat()`.)

Comment: If you test if two or more bits are set, you need to do a strict equal instead of just an implicit "is not none": `bits & 0b1100 == 0b1100`

Answer (score 14):

Bitwise left-shifting and bitwise AND operator is your friend.
In general you can check if the nth bit is set/unset as below:

```
if (x & (1<<n)) 
  ## n-th bit is set (1)

else 
  ## n-th bit is not set (0)
```

Comment: @Cyber :) - oops.. problems with working on multiple languages at the same time.. Edited.. Thx

Answer (score 5):

You can use bit shifting

```
>>> 0b10010101 >> 4 & 1
1
>>> 0b10010101 >> 3 & 1
0
```

Comment: And don't forget those parenthesis for clarity. :)

Answer (score 4):

```
bits = 0b11010011

if bits & (1 << 3):
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. i looked at the bit comparison but the description didn't help to much.

Answer (score 2):

```
bits = '1110111'

if bits[-4] == '0':
    print "......false"
else:
    print  "....true"
```

Comment: not sure why this was downvoted its a perfectly valid aproach that can even be faster than the other methods(in some circumstances) ....

Comment: If the bit sequence is already a string, this is the best approach.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming integers, if you are counting Left Hand (LH), Most Significant Bit (MSB) to the Right Hand (RH) Lease Significant Bit (LSB):

```
def check_bitL2R(byte, bit):
    return bool(byte & (0b10000000>>bit))
```

Reverse if you want to count LSB towards the MSB:

```
def check_bitR2L(byte, bit):
    return bool(byte & (0b1<<bit))
```

Then check that:

```
fmt='{:^5} {:^5} {:^5}'
print fmt.format(*'bit  LSB  MSB'.split())
for bit in range(8):
    print fmt.format(bit, check_bitR2L(0b10010101, bit), check_bitL2R(0b10010101, bit))
```

Prints:

```
 bit   LSB   MSB 
  0     1     1  
  1     0     0  
  2     1     0  
  3     0     1  
  4     1     0  
  5     0     1  
  6     0     0  
  7     1     1
```